# How to achieve pagination in SQL Server 2008 with like statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pagination

My query for pagination result is

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNum,
         *
     FROM 
         My_Table) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE 
    (RowNum >= 1 AND RowNum <= 10)
ORDER BY 
    RowNum
```

This works fine. But when I try this for search result with like statement, it didn't work.

Search query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNum,
         *
     FROM 
         My_Table) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE 
    column1 LIKE '%search%'
    AND (RowNum >= 1 AND RowNum <= 10)
ORDER BY 
    RowNum
```

If first 10 rows don't contains search value, its return 0 results instead looking for full table. I can't use offset and fetch because it doesn't support in SQL Server 2008.

Any better way to use for pagination which work fine for like and normal in SQL Server 2008

Thanks

Comment: I have formatted your question and found that your second query lacks operator before `(RowNum >= 1`; I added `AND` but you may review for correctness.

Comment: thanks, but this is not issue

Comment: I'm not taking about the issue; I'm saying I added something that was not present so you can look back and update your question with correct details to get correct answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close.. I'd use a CTE to filter, then select your 10 rows from it.

```
;WITH X AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNum, *
    FROM My_Table 
    WHERE column1 LIKE '%search%'
)

SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY RowNum
```

Depending on your situation, you may be able to simply get away with:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNum
FROM My_Table 
WHERE column1 LIKE '%search%'
ORDER BY RowNum
```